# material-ui using Autocomplete with diff value,option type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, material-ui

I only want to store a id of an option in a value

Autocomplete looks value's type and option's type must be same

so i try change value in onChange it work's

but renderOption is not work well

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sun-s4x9y

here is my last tryed sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `renderTags` property on the `Autocomplete` component:

```
renderTags={(value, getTagProps) => (
  <>
  {value.map((id, index) => (
    <Chip
      label={values.find(o => o.id === id)?.name}
      {...getTagProps({index})}
    />
  ))}
  </>
)}
```

The `getTagProps` function handles setting the `onDelete` handler for the `Chip`.  We have to manually set the `label` for the `Chip` by finding the option that matches this `id` and returning its `name`.